# How to put three values into one array php and put it foreach?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to put three value into one array instead of two. Like below code, how can I achieve that?

```js
$emo_word = array(
  "LOL !" => 'lol' => 1, 
  "COOL !" => 'cool'=> 2, 
  "CUTE !" => 'cute' =>3, 
  "LOVE IT !" => 'love_it'=>4
);  
foreach( $emo_word as $first=> $second => $third)
{
  //code here
}
```

Comment: This is not JavaScript!!!

Comment: you can't do the first one so you can't do the foreach you want either. Provide an explanation of what your goal is

Comment: What are you trying to do in the loop?

Comment: you could use list: http://php.net/manual/de/function.list.php

Answer (score 3):

The syntax is wrong here:

```
$emo_word = array(
  "LOL !" => 'lol' => 1, 
  //---------------^
  "COOL !" => 'cool'=> 2, 
  "CUTE !" => 'cute' =>3, 
  "LOVE IT !" => 'love_it'=>4
);

foreach( $emo_word as $first=> $second => $third)
//-------------------------------------^
{
  //code here
}
```

You may need to use an array instead. And it should look like this?

```
$emo_word = array(
  1 => array("LOL !", 'lol')
  2 => array("COOL !", 'cool'),
  3 => array("CUTE !", 'cute'),
  4 => array("LOVE IT !", 'love_it')
);
```

This depends on what you are exactly wishing to do. If you feel that thos `LOL !` and others are the identifiers, keep them as indices.

Comment: The php documentation is pretty good if you decide to use an associative array with the LOL ! and others as identifiers http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: I want to put a ID on each word, so that's why I put 1,2,3,4.  can I get the number 1,2,3,4 by using the code you suggest?

Comment: Thanks, how can I put into a foreach loop? Could you provide an example?

Comment: @conan You can have a look at: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to keep it like you had it you would do it like this

```
$emo_word = array(
  "LOL !" => array('lol' => 1),
  "COOL !" => array('cool'=> 2,),
  "CUTE !" => array('cute' =>3),
  "LOVE IT !" => array('love_it'=>4)
);
```

to access LOL ! and get the 1 you would go like this:

```
$emo_word['LOL !']['lol']
```

Comment: What if I want to get 'LOL !' in the code you provide?

Comment: You could do a foreach like foreach($emo_word as $key => $value) then the $key would have all the key values like 'LOL !'

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the list-command:

```
$emo_world= array(
   array("LOL !", "lol", 1),
   array("COOL !", "cool", 2),
   array("CUTE !", "cute", 3),
);
foreach($emo_world as $world){
  list($first, $second, $third) = $world;
  echo "Here you go: ".$first." and ".$second." and ".$third; 
}
```

I did not test it though, but this should be the way to go.
Hope this helps.

http://php.net/manual/de/function.list.php